# Can't use jquery to target elements rendered with Mustache.js

Tags: jquery, templates, mustache

I have a problem

I've created a template with Mustache.js (example):

```
<script type="text/template" id="info">
  <div id="info-content">
    {{>photoEl}}                
  </div>
</script>
```

with certain elements being created and added as partials (example):

```
partials.photoEl = '<span class="photo"><a class="button" href="#"></a></span>';
```

but I can't target any of the elements using jQuery.

```
$('.button').click(function(event){
  console.log('click');
});
```

Does nothing...

Any idea why?

Comment: Why is your div inside the script tag o.o? if you're adding the handler the element is not in DOM you will need to add a delegated event to the .button because it's created after the DOM is ready by mustache(If is created).

Answer (score 8):

Use `event delegation` this will add the handler for future elements.

If you use `$(".button")` and the element is not in the DOM already the event handler will not work because noting will be selected

```
$(document).on("click",".button",function(){
  console.log('click');
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it had to be something to do with the template not being part of the DOM...

Comment: Yw, I hope it helped you.